# What's the difference between OpenZeppelin's IERC vs ERC contracts?

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm using the contracts OpenZeppelin provides, but I don't understand why there is 2 version of the same one. Why is there an I version vs non-I?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

- IERC is the Interface for the token contract.
- ERC is the implementation of the token contract.

---

Interfaces are like blueprints, to make sure a *Class* (in our case, a *Contract*) implementation has the right methods, with the right method visibility, parameters and return values.

A method on IERC file:

```
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
```

It does not hold code, but has some valuable information:

- it has name `balanceOf`.
- it takes one parameter of type `address`, and name `account`.
- it is a "read only" method, based on `view`.
- it returns a `uint256` value.
- it DOES NOT have code.

The same method on the ERC file:

```
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
```

- it HAS code.

Note that the ERC20 file imports the IERC20 file and defines that on line 33: `ERC20 is a IERC20`. In other words: "ERC20 should implement methods from interface IERC20".

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! If I'm creating my own NFT token, should I inherit from the implementation or the interface?

Comment: from the interface, definitely.

Comment: It looks like Interfaces are to Implementations what header `.h` files are to `.c` files in C.